# Test the API of Running WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, automation

I would like to test the `API of WPF` application that is already running.

The application is single window application and its `MainWindow` holds object that I would like to fetch (`it's public and has public methods and properties`)

Is there a way I can go from Gui or Process to the under layer and fetch exist object?

```
// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    //this is the object to be fetch
    public AppAPI AppAPI { get; private set; } }

public class AppAPI
{
    private void IncrementCounter(){...}

    public int GetClickCounter(){...}

    public void Click(){...}

    public void Launch(){...}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are talking about is inter-process communication in .NET - which is a complex subject and would require a significant re-factoring of your application in order for it to offer such a feature. I think WCF over named pipes would be a good starting point

Comment: Thank you for your response. Isn't there GetObject VB style option?